# Xcode 6 GM not launching on OS X Yosemite

Tags: xcode, crash, osx-yosemite-beta, xcode6gm

Xcode 6 GM isn't running on my Yosemite Build 7.
The Icon bounces up and down on the dock until I quit the application.

I have tried re-installing and the issue persists.
I have also tried Xcode 5.1.1 and Xcode 6 beta.

Any ideas?

Comment: try to wait longer time. Sure, first launch is boring long

Comment: Is this the first launch after downloading?  If so, people have reported up to 10 minutes waiting before it finishes.

Comment: Just after reading these, I tried to launch the application again ready to wait a long time, but it launched instantly, not quite sure what was happening, thanks anyway guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply let the application take its time to load, it can take a while. After this it should load fine the following times.